# HTML to PHP navigation bar

Tags: php, html

I got this navigation bar and i dont know how to convert it from HTML to PHP. Can somone help me?

The HTML is

```
<nav>
<div id="menubar">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li  class="current"><a href="index.php?pg=1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="rpg.php?pg=2">RPG</a></li>
        <li><a href="sports.php?pg=3">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="strategy.php?pg=4">Strategy</a></li>
        <li><a href="android_ios.php?pg=5">Android/IOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="nice_to_try.php?pg=6">Nice to try</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I'm just beginner in PHP and im trying to learn the code, i searched it up on google but i couldnt figure out how to apply it to my code.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you don't quite understand what each of them is used for.
What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to produce the html code server-side? 
There isn't such a thing as "migrating HTML to PHP". They are two very different things. HTML is a markup language (used to present the content to the user), PHP is a programming language

Comment: frankly speakin, if you do not wish to manage it from an admin panel, you should leave it as it is. HTML is the fastest to render ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pedram's straight-forward answer, now let's get introduced to looping...

```
<?php 

/**
 * Hold Menu links and labels inside $menuLinks array
 **/
$menuLinks = [
'index.php?pg=' => 'Home',
'rpg.php?pg=' => 'RPG',
'sports.php?pg=' => 'Sports',
'strategy.php?pg=' => 'Strategy',
'android_ios.php?pg=' => 'Android/IOS',
'nice_to_try.php?pg=' => 'Nice to try'
];
/**
 * Introduce $menuLiList for storing <li>...</li> html.
 **/
$menuLiList = null;
/**
 * Introduce $i counter
 **/
$i = 1;
/**
 * inside foreach loop, take each link and label and build html
 **/
foreach($menuLinks as $link => $label){
    /**
     * if $i is 1, add current class to the li, i.e. add current class to the first element.
     **/
    $current = $i == 1 ? 'class="current"' : '';
    /**
     * append html
     **/
    $menuLiList .= '<li  '.$current.'><a href="'.$link.$i.'">'.$label.'</a></li>';
    /**
     * increase counter.
     **/
    $i++;
}
/**
 * Finally, echo what you have in list, plus the outer wrapper.
 **/
echo '<nav>
<div id="menubar">
    <ul id="nav">
        '.$menuLiList.'
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>';
```

Is it needed? Not really in your case, but this should be a good example how programming languages ease our daily-life problems.  Logic may vary greatly depending on you you need. Update your question for a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `echo` to `print` html tags:

```
<?php
echo '
<nav>
<div id="menubar">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li  class="current"><a href="index.php?pg=1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="rpg.php?pg=2">RPG</a></li>
        <li><a href="sports.php?pg=3">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="strategy.php?pg=4">Strategy</a></li>
        <li><a href="android_ios.php?pg=5">Android/IOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="nice_to_try.php?pg=6">Nice to try</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
';
?>
```

**For make a dynamic `ul li` see this links:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5581200/4540183

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17638336/4540183

Comment: That's too easy, Maybe a little more challeging. I know there are ways to convert it to full PHP and that's the answer i'm looking for. I can't figure out how to do it with my code. Apprieciate your response though, but not the answer i'm looking for.

Comment: PHP is only going to print the html as in this answer.  Thats what php does, it allows you to template according to preprocessing instructions.

Comment: You want to `print` a `html` code or you want make `ul li` dynamically with `PHP` ? @RainierLaan

Comment: I want to make ul li dynamically with php, but i dont know how thats why i'm here.

Comment: Ok, you must to clearify what you want in question, anyway. it's too easy just look at these links that added to answer. @RainierLaan

Answer (score 0):

You don't really convert it...
At the end of the day, PHP outputs a HTML file in browser.
You can have mixed HTML, Javascript, PHP in your code. The browser can understand all of them. Just use correct tags.

Just use `echo`.
Echo prints out your HTML code.

Will be like

```
<?php
echo '
<nav>
<div id="menubar">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li  class="current"><a href="index.php?pg=1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="rpg.php?pg=2">RPG</a></li>
        <li><a href="sports.php?pg=3">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="strategy.php?pg=4">Strategy</a></li>
        <li><a href="android_ios.php?pg=5">Android/IOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="nice_to_try.php?pg=6">Nice to try</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
';
?>
```

See your code as a quotation.